# I don't know how to size box from the start of an contraction zone to the end of the contraction pinescript indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I've been trying to make an indicator that finds contraction zones but I am confused I was able to highlight the contraction zones with the white labels but I want a box that is sized from start and ends at the end of the contraction which is from the first white label to the last label I am completely lost at this point since the closest I get to is making a box for each label down but it isn't going to work for what I need it for

How it looks like, (white box isnt part of it)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IQC0.png
How I want it to look
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm1Us.png

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="ATR Contraction", shorttitle="ATR CONTRACTION FINDER", overlay=true, precision=3, max_lines_count = 500, max_boxes_count = 500)
lenAtr = input(title = "atr length", defval = 1)
atr = ta.atr(lenAtr)
//atr values
avg5 = input.int(title="WMA", defval=5)
avg13 = input.int(title="WMA",  defval=13)
avg22 = input.int(title="WMA",  defval=22)

WMA5 = ta.wma (atr, avg5)
WMA13 = ta.wma (atr, avg13)
WMA22 = ta.wma (atr,avg22)

//STD
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
stdev = ta.stdev( src , length)
STDWMA13 = ta.wma (stdev, avg13)
STDWMA22 = ta.wma (stdev,avg22)
ifStd = stdev < STDWMA13 and STDWMA13 < STDWMA22

// volume
VWMA5 = ta.wma ( volume ,5)
VWMA10 = ta.wma ( volume ,10)
VWMA20 = ta.wma ( volume ,20)
ifVMA = VWMA5 < VWMA10 and VWMA10 < VWMA20



string tfInput = input.timeframe("D", "Timeframe")
var hi = float(na)
var lo = float(na)
var line hiLine = na
var line loLine = na
var box hiLoBox = na
// Detect changes in timeframe.
if lessVolatility? 1:na
    // New bar in higher timeframe; reset values and create new lines and box.
    hi := high
    lo := low
    hiLoBox := box.new(bar_index -1 , hi, bar_index+5, lo, border_color = na, bgcolor = color.silver)
    box.set_bgcolor(hiLoBox, color.new(color.blue, 50))
    int(na)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you get the singal for first time, you can set a variable to true and keep setting it to true until signal continues. And based on that variable you can create a new box when its set for first time, and keep extending it for one bar if it was already true from before. Example

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="ATR Contraction", shorttitle="ATR CONTRACTION FINDER", overlay=true, precision=3, max_lines_count = 500, max_boxes_count = 500)
lenAtr = input(title = "atr length", defval = 1)
atr = ta.atr(lenAtr)
//atr values
avg5 = input.int(title="WMA", defval=5)
avg13 = input.int(title="WMA",  defval=13)
avg22 = input.int(title="WMA",  defval=22)

WMA5 = ta.wma (atr, avg5)
WMA13 = ta.wma (atr, avg13)
WMA22 = ta.wma (atr,avg22)

ifAtr = atr < WMA5 and WMA5 < WMA13 and WMA13 < WMA22

//STD
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
stdev = ta.stdev( src , length)
STDWMA13 = ta.wma (stdev, avg13)
STDWMA22 = ta.wma (stdev,avg22)
ifStd = stdev < STDWMA13 and STDWMA13 < STDWMA22

// volume
VWMA5 = ta.wma ( volume ,5)
VWMA10 = ta.wma ( volume ,10)
VWMA20 = ta.wma ( volume ,20)
ifVMA = VWMA5 < VWMA10 and VWMA10 < VWMA20

lessVolatility = ifAtr and ifStd and ifVMA

string tfInput = input.timeframe("D", "Timeframe")
var hi = float(na)
var lo = float(na)
var line hiLine = na
var line loLine = na
var box hiLoBox = na
// Detect changes in timeframe.
var continuebox=false

if lessVolatility? 1:na
    // New bar in higher timeframe; reset values and create new lines and box.
    hi := high
    lo := low
    if continuebox
        box.set_right(hiLoBox,bar_index)
    else
        hiLoBox := box.new(bar_index -1 , hi, bar_index, lo, border_color = na, bgcolor = color.silver)
        box.set_bgcolor(hiLoBox, color.new(color.blue, 50))
    int(na)
    continuebox:=true
else
    continuebox:=false



plotshape(lessVolatility? 1:na,style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.white, size=size.tiny)
```